# How to use android holo color generator?

Tags: android

Can some one in explain me in layman perspective how to use [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/)
If I generate app theme name as `AppTheme_Test` and then putting all the res folder and then mentioning in manifest like `android:theme="@style/AppTheme_Test" >` It is not working, ie not taking color effect of Button, though I selected the button color in the generator. How to use it ?

Comment: [Go through this](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons)

Comment: @Mohit without answering my question you have given a link. My strait forward question is how to use the generator?

Comment: ok ...check my answer

Answer (score 0):

At website link I have posted there is an option Download ZIP..*HIT it..*

- Extract it where you want.
- Extracted file contains `res` folder, copy and replace `res` folder in your project *(I recommend to merge style file with present file)*.
- Define element in layout file with background from `drawable` folder..
- It will reflect your holo generated ..

[image]